# Can write to, but can't read from serial port ttyS0 in linux C program

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I'm trying to learn how to program the ttyS0 serial port in Linux using C.  I have another machine connected to my serial port sending alternating hex values of 5f and 6f about every two seconds.  I've verified with other port monitoring apps that these values are appearing at the port.  In my code I'm using a blocking **read()** into a 10 char length buffer.  Even though my other machine is still sending data, **read()** blocks forever.  If I include the line **fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);** which sets read() to non-blocking read() always returns with a value of -1, meaning no data was in the UART buffer, and my for loop code just prints out random values that are in the buffer.  So in short my assumption is that my code is not reading ttyS0 and I have no idea why.  Below is my code, hopefully someone will see what's causing my problem and set me straight.  By the way, I'm using Scientific Linux, I believe ttyS0 is com port 1, as it is in RedHat and Fedora. Aslo below is the output when i run the code.  It seems to be writing to the COM port with no problems, but for a read it says its unavailable.  Also it's clear that the buffer I'm printing out is just random values not data that's been read in.  Thanks

### console output

```
hello world
hi again
write error: : Success
 wrote 4 bytes
number of bytes read is -1
read error:: Resource temporarily unavailable
4  8  120  -99  -73  -65  41  -120  4  8  
should of put something out
```

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    int n;
    int fd;
    char c;
    int bytes;

    char buffer[10];
    char *bufptr;
    int nbytes;
    int tries;
    int x;
    struct termios options;


    fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open_port: Unable to open:");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("hi again\n");
    }

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);

    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;
    options.c_cflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE |ISIG );
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY );
    options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);


    write(fd, "ATZ\r",4);
    printf(" wrote\n");
    bufptr = buffer;


    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
     bytes = read(fd, bufptr, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("number of bytes read is %d\n", bytes);
    perror ("read error:");

    for (x = 0; x < 10 ; x++)
    {
        c = buffer[x];
        printf("%d  ",c);
    }
    close(fd);

    //puts(buffer[0]);
    printf("\nshould of put something out \n");

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: one of the possibilities is another application may be reading the data simultaneously. I had the same issue some times ago. At that time I was doing cat /dev/ttyS0 on other shell and trying to write and read using a program on an other shell.

Comment: This looks like a repost/duplicate/revision of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242648/programming-linux-serial-port-ttys0

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `MIN` and/or `TIME` values:

```
/*...*/
options.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; //read() will return after receiving 1 character
options.c_cc[VTIME] = 0; // == 0 - infinite timeout, != 0 - sets timeout in deciseconds
/*...*/
tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);
```

The given example will set your read() to return after getting any symbol and to wait indefinitely for input. Naturally, you may play with these parameters as you see fit (e.g. set MIN to 10 if you want).

You may want to remove `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);` call for this to work though.

It is also wise to save previous termios settings and restore them before leaving your program.