# Making a blocking read() from UART on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, arm, uart

I am trying to write to the serial port (sending a handshake) and then subsequently I try to read the serial port. When reading the port, I notice I am getting garbage reads (even if there is nothing connected to the RX line) or part of the write string I am sending to the TX line. Why am I getting part of that string? I am not supposed to be seeing that!

Here is my code:

```
   class UART{

    public:
        UART();
        ~UART();
        int open_port();
        int configure_port(); // All port configurations such as parity, baud rate, hardware flow, etc
        int uart_write(std::string);     // Send characters to the serial port
        int uart_read(std::string*, int);            // Read from serial port
        // Close
        void close_port();

    private:
        int fd;
```

uart.cpp:

```
UART::UART(){
    open_port();
    configure_port();
}

UART::~UART(){
    close_port();
}

int UART::open_port()
{
    // Open ttys4
    fd = open("/dev/ttyS4", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

    if(fd == -1) // if open is unsucessful
    {
        //perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");
        printf("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS4. \n");
    }
    else
    {
        fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
        printf("port is open.\n");
    }

    return(fd);
} //open_port

// configure the port
int UART::configure_port()      
{
    struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in

    cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);    // set baud rates
    cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);

    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;
    port_settings.c_cflag |=  CREAD | CLOCAL;     // turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines

    port_settings.c_cc[VTIME]     =   10;                  // n seconds read timeout
    port_settings.c_iflag     &=  ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // turn off s/w flow ctrl
    port_settings.c_lflag     &=  ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG); // make raw
    port_settings.c_oflag     &=  ~OPOST;              // make raw

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
    return(fd);
} 

 // Write to serial port
int UART::uart_write(string data)  
{
    int buffer_size = data.length();
    char * data_write = new char[data.length()+1];
    strcpy (data_write, data.c_str());

    int n = write(fd, data_write, buffer_size);  //Send data

    usleep(1000);
    tcdrain(fd);

    printf("Wrote the bytes. \n");

    /* Error Handling */
    int status = 0;
    if (n < 0)
    {
         cout << "Error Writing: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
         status = 0;
    }else{
        status = 1;
    }

    delete[] data_write;

    return status;
}

int UART::uart_read(string *data,int buffer_size)
{
    // Buffer
    char * buf = new char[buffer_size+1];

    usleep(1000);
    tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH);

    // Read
    /*I NEED THIS PART TO BE BLOCKING*/
    int n = read( fd, buf , buffer_size );

    /* Error Handling */
    if (n < 0)
    {
         cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }

    // String received
    string data_received(buf,buffer_size);
    *data = data_received;

    delete[] buf;

    cout << "data_received: " << *data << endl;

    // Did we get blank data?
    if( data_received.length() == 0 )
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

main

```
int main()
{ 
    UART uart_connection;

    string handshake = "handshake!";
    uart_connection.uart_write(handshake);

    string data;
    string *data_ptr = &data;
    uart_connection.uart_read(data_ptr );

    cout << data << endl;

}
```

When printing the received data, I usually get part of the sent data. So on cout << data << endl I am getting the following:

```
dshake
```

along with some weird characters after it, or if I don't write anything to the serial port then I just get random characters.

Specifically I want **int n = read( fd, buf , buffer_size );** to be a blocking function, which apparently it's not happening... It just goes through and it returns a bunch of weird characters or it reads part of the string sent with write.

Please note that the code works and when I do actually send something to the RX line, I can read it just fine. However, I am finding it difficult to send large chunks of data without getting bad reads.

I believe this could all be solved if I could make the read() function a blocking function, and avoid it reading those weird characters.

Comment: Your termios initialization is incomplete: you configure non-canonical mode but fail to set the VMIN parameter.  Study https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680  BTW **read()** does not return a string.  Maybe that's why you think there's *"garbage reads"*; you're not processing the buffer correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`Read` is always allowed to read less than what you asked for. To make it "block" until you have read enough characters, you need to wrap it in a loop and call it until you've read however many bytes you wanted.

In your code, `n` is the number of bytes that were read successfully. You only ever check that it is non-negative.

The loop would probably look like this:

```
size_t read_count = 0;
while (read_count < buffer_size)
{
    ssize_t read_result = read(fd, buf + read_count, buffer_size - read_count);
    if (read_result < 0)
    {
        cout << "Error reading: " << strerror(errno) << endl;
        break;
    }
    read_count += read_result;
}
```

Note that generally speaking, `read` is a low-level interface with lots of easy-to-miss subtleties. For instance, on error, it's worth checking for `EINTR` and maybe a few others.

Off the top of my head, `FILE*` functions don't have these issues, and you may be able to use `fdopen` and `fread` to consistently get what you want.

Although it appears that you haven't had that problem yet, `write` has the same set of issues. It is also allowed to write fewer bytes than you gave it, and it can be interrupted too. However, this rarely happens with small writes.

Comment: Do you think using fread() would solve this other issue I am having...? The other issue is that I can't seem to read accurately data on the serial port where the buffer size is larger than ~32 bytes. It always fails when reading large data.

Comment: @LuisCruz  *"It always fails when reading large data."* -- That's because you ignore the return code, which, when positive, is the number of valid bytes in the buffer.