# Is there a way to set minimum characters per read using fcntl()?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

In Linux command `stty` we can set the N characters minimum for a completed read using the option `min`.

From stty man

```
min N
    with -icanon, set N characters minimum for a completed read 
time N
    with -icanon, set read timeout of N tenths of a second
```

Is there a way to set these options [ `min` and `time`] using `fcntl()` or any `C` `API`'s. I checked the `fcntl()` and `open()` man , but couldn't find a matching flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Linux command `stty` we can set the N characters minimum for a completed read using the option min.

> Is there a way to set these options [ min and time] using fcntl() or any C API's.

The `stty` command is merely a command that accesses the termios interface (of a serial terminal).
Programmatically you can use **tcgetattr()** and **tcsetattr()**.

See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-Modes.html)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/%7Estrupp/serial.html)

---

Sample C code that sets the deciseconds and minimum-count for a raw read of an open serial terminal:

```
int set_time_and_min(int fd, int time, int min)
{
  struct termios settings;
  int result;

  result = tcgetattr(fd, &settings);
  if (result < 0) {
      perror("error in tcgetattr");
      return -1;
  }
  settings.c_cc[VTIME] = time;
  settings.c_cc[VMIN] = min;
  result = tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &settings);
  if (result < 0) {
      perror("error in tcsetattr");
      return -2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

> I checked the fcntl() and open() man , but couldn't find a matching flag.

The man page to reference is termios(3).

---

Of course the VMIN and VTIME values are only effective when using blocking noncanonical I/O.  See [Linux Blocking vs. non Blocking Serial Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680)

Comment: I realized that I can not use fcntl() to set VMIn and VTIME. So the alternative option is termios and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean [the POSIX `ssize_t read(int fildes, void *buf, size_t nbyte)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), no.  There is no standard way to set a minimum number of bytes to be `read()`. (I can't rule out some implementations providing the capability, but I'm not aware of any, nor for the reasons to follow do I see a point in providing such a capability to `read()` in general.)

And for a very good reason:  what happens if the bytes run out before the number requested is met?  The other end of the pipe gets closed, the socket you're reading from gets shut down, or you hit the end of the file you're reading from before reaching the requested number of bytes.

What should `read()` do then?  Block forever waiting for bytes that either might never or can never arrive?  In that case, the only sensible action is for `read()` to return the number of bytes that have been read.

So in general you must handle partial `read()` results anyway, making the "read a minimum number of bytes" setting pointless.