# Cannot read data from terminal until restarted by other process

Tags: terminal, uart, termios

Before adding `O_NOCTTY` option, my process was killed once by unknown per every booting. I don't know why the process was killed :( and I thought the initializing has some problems. **so that I added `O_NOCTTY` option, and the process was not killed. But it cannot read any data from the buffer until restarted by other process.** Please help me :(
The following is code about initializing and reading.

```
void Init() {
    mFd = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);

    if (mFd > 0)
    {
        (void)tcgetattr(mFd, &mTermios_p);
        speed = B115200;
        mTermios_p.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
        mTermios_p.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
        mTermios_p.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
        mTermios_p.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
        mTermios_p.c_cflag |= CS8;
        mTermios_p.c_cc[VMIN] = 0U;
        mTermios_p.c_cc[VTIME] = 0U;
        (void)cfsetispeed(&mTermios_p, speed);
        (void)cfsetospeed(&mTermios_p, speed);
        (void)tcflush(mFd, TCIOFLUSH);
        (void)tcsetattr(mFd, TCSANOW, &mTermios_p);
    }
    else
    {
        LOGE("uart open failed %s", strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

```
int32_t Read() {
    int32_t bytes = -1;
    if (mFd > 0)
    {
        (void)pthread_mutex_lock(&mMutexLock);
        bytes = static_cast<int32_t>(read(mFd, buf, nMaxRead));
        (void)pthread_mutex_unlock(&mMutexLock);
    }

    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        LOGE("read failed");
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serial terminal initialization is essentially the near-equivalent of **cfmakeraw()** plus setting the baudrate.
However that is insufficient to fully initialize a serial terminal.

At the very least the receiver also has to be enabled:

```
mTermios_p.c_cflag |= CREAD;
```

To eliminate any modem handshake issues (especially when there is no modem):

```
mTermios_p.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
```

To eliminate any hardware handshake issues:

```
mTermios_p.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
```

---

BTW

```
    mTermios_p.c_cc[VMIN] = 0U;
    mTermios_p.c_cc[VTIME] = 0U;
```

Setting both **VMIN** and **VTIME** to zero is an ill-advised configuration.
[This guide](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html) describes this configuration as one that should be used only if *"you really, really know what you're doing."*
The code that you posted for reading is not capable of (efficiently) handling the consequences of setting both **VMIN** and **VTIME** to zero.  Unless your program is synchronized with the transmitting program, your read code is likely to "successfully" read zero bytes, i.e. no data.

Comment: I'm wondering between following 2 settings, which difference exists. 1. `mFd = open(..., ... | O_NONBLOCK)...mTermios_p.c_cc[VMIN] = 1U ` 2.`mFd = open(..., ...)...mTermios_p.c_cc[VMIN] = 0U`        Are both 2 settings operating non-blocking mode??

Comment: @John -- Essentially similar, but **read()** could return different codes, e.g. -1 with errno=EAGAIN versus zero.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way,as I mentioned in the original question, after adding `O_NOCTTY` flag, the process cannot read anything via uart and it operates well after killed once by other process. I'm confused where should I debug first.

Comment: @John -- You have provided zero details about the involved processes. Processes normally do not interact nor interfere with each other.  Somehow you have created dependencies between processes.  You have not posted a minimal reproducible example as expected for this site.  Apparently your code makes extensive use of global variables, and unexplained use of a mutex.  I'm not going to guess how to debug such unknowns.    You have posted your termios initialization, and I have pointed out that it is incomplete.  You have posted some read code, and I have pointed out its limitations.

Comment: IOW I have provided a solution to the termios side of your reading problem.  The inter-processing conflict(s) is IMO a separate issue.