# Need advice on serial port software access implementation on single CPU core device

Tags: serial-port, real-time, modbus, openwrt, termios

I am designing the software controlling several serial ports, operating system is OpenWrt. The device application is running in is single core ARM9 @ 450 MHz. Protocol for serial ports is Modbus.

The problem is with Modbus slave implementation. I designed it in real-time manner, looping reading data from serial port (port is open in non-blocking mode with 0 characters to wait for and no timeouts). The sequence/data stream timeout is about 4 milliseconds @ 9600/8/N/1 (3.5 characters as advised). Timeout is checked if application does not see anything in the buffer, therefore if application is slower that incoming stream of characters, timeouts mechanism will not take place - until all characters are removed from the buffer and bus is quiet.

But I see that CPU switches between threads and this thread is missed for about 40-60 milliseconds, which is a lot to measure timeouts. While I guess serial port buffer still receives the data (how long this buffer is?), *I am unable to assess how much time passed between chars*, and may treat next message as continuation of previous and miss Modbus request targeted for my device.

Therefore, I guess, something must be redesigned (for the slave - master is different story). First idea coming to my mind is to forget about timeouts, and just parse the incoming data after being synchronized with the whole stream (by finding initial timeout). However, there're several problems - I must know everything about all types of Modbus messages to parse them correctly and find out their ends and where next message starts, and I do not see the way how to differentiate Modbus request with Modbus response from the device. If developers of the Modbus protocol would put special bit in command field identifying if message is request or response... but it is not the case, and I do not see the right way to identify if message I am getting is request or response without getting following bytes and checking CRC16 at would-be byte counts, it will cost time while I am getting bytes, and may miss window for the response to request targeted for me.

Another idea would be using blocking method with VTIME timeout setting, but this value may be set to tenths of seconds only (therefore minimal is 100 ms), and this is too much given another +50 ms for possible CPU switching between threads, I think something like timeout of 10 ms is needed here. It is a good question if VTIME is hardware time, or software/driver also subject to CPU thread interruptions; and the size of FIFO in the chip/driver how many bytes it can accumulate.

Any help/idea/advice will be greatly appreciated.

Update per @sawdust comments:

1. non-blocking use has really appeared not a good way because I do not poll hardware, I poll software, and the whole design is again subject to CPU switching and execution scheduling;
2. "using the built-in event-based blocking mode" would work in blocking mode if I would be able to configure UART timeout (VTIME) in 100 us periods, plus if again I would be sure I am not interrupted during the executing - only then I will be able to have timing properly, and restart reading in time to get next character's timing assessed properly.

Comment: *"port is open in non-blocking mode with 0 characters to wait for and no timeouts"* -- That's not going to help at all because your userspace code executes asynchronously with respect to UART events and executes only when scheduled.  You're just going to inefficiently poll the system buffer, instead of using the built-in event-based blocking mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read

Comment: Best way to measure/detect the end-of-message idle time is with hardware.  Atmel/Microchip USARTs (in SAM9 and SAMA5 SOCs) have a receiver timeout that can reliably perform this task.  Accurately measuring this timeout in userspace is futile.

Comment: @sawdust first your comment is clear; second: as far as I see there're no ways to perform the task using standard UART capabilities and OpenWrt kernel/software. The device I develop for uses i.MX28 single core CPU. Would you agree that to implement Modbus timing properly I will need additional hardware/controller?

Comment: VTIME has nothing to do with UART timing, so it's worthless for your requirement.  It refers to data timing from the driver, which will also buffer the data, e.g. using DMA.  See [Linux serial drivers](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).  I don't know about needing additional HW.  Maybe a timer could be added to the UART driver's receive handler.  Interrupt latency would be a concern.  The driver would have to use programmed I/O rather than DMA. Just be sure you try to measure a timeout, and not the time between received bytes.