Where does read(2) check the termios struct to determine that it should read STDIN in an (un)blocking fashion?
I have searched:

the standard library (figured the answer isn't there because there is a dead end of libc_hidden_def which is apparently something that connects to the kernel)
xfce4-terminal source code
the Linux kernel

and still failed to find the answer that will explain how read(2) knows that is has to block or not block. Yes, read(2) is not the fuction containing the answer, but it is the starting point.
Here I will draw the timeline of the problem:

tcsetattr(set VMIN and VTIME to get raw mode or some other combo)
read(try to read from STDIN)
???
something somewhere checks the termios struct that we have set, and decides whether to keep polling STDIN until a newline comes, until x characters are inside, until x time has passed, or always return whatever is (not) inside
we get the result of read()


hi I have searched: the Linux kernel it's there, you did not search good enough ; ) . Read system call is in the kernel, TTY is also there.

It's the terminal that does the "blocking", and the termios settings are sent to it. On a kernel level you should look at the PTY and TTY devices, it might be there. If not then you need to follow the tcsetattr call instead of the read call.

You're conflating several possible modes that the serial terminal can use. The attributes VMIN and VTIME are only used when both (1) non-canonical mode is specified and (2) the serial terminal was open in blocking mode (i.e. O_NONBLOCK is not specified). Othwise VMIN and VTIME are meaningless and not used. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read You need to refine your question.

See Linux serial drivers

"something somewhere ... decides whether to keep polling ..." - Faulty assertion; there is no polling. The logic is event-driven by data received from the device-driver layer or a timer.


Where does read(2) check the termios struct to determine that it should read STDIN in an (un)blocking fashion?

In the Linux kernel in TTY implementation. Related documentation https://docs.kernel.org/driver-api/tty/index.html .
First we need the macros from https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/tty.h#L40 :
#define TIME_CHAR(tty) ((tty)->termios.c_cc[VTIME])
#define MIN_CHAR(tty) ((tty)->termios.c_cc[VMIN])

Looks like VMIN and VTIME is used around here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2212 :
static ssize_t n_tty_read(struct tty_struct *tty, struct file *file, u8 *kbuf,
              size_t nr, void **cookie, unsigned long offset)
{
    .......
    minimum = time = 0;
    timeout = MAX_SCHEDULE_TIMEOUT;
    if (!ldata->icanon) {
        minimum = MIN_CHAR(tty);
        if (minimum) {
            time = (HZ / 10) * TIME_CHAR(tty);
        } else {
            timeout = (HZ / 10) * TIME_CHAR(tty);
            minimum = 1;
        }
    }
    ......
                timeout = wait_woken(&wait, TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE,
                        timeout);

    ......
    if (kb - kbuf >= minimum)
        break;
    if (time)
        timeout = time;


Amazing. could you please just add the connection how to get from read(2) to this? I have started with read in the kernel, which goes: read > SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read > ksys_read > vfs_read >  file->f_op->read(file, buf, count, pos); ... which is, what, a function pointer? so I'm lost at this point. I have not gone from the back to the front because n_tty_read seems to only exist in n_tty.c, and nowhere else. EDIT2: ok, it seems it is a static function that is linked in the function pointer struct called tty_ldisc_ops

which is, what, a function pointer? Yes, and the function depends on what you are connected to. There is no simple "get to this", a specific driver implements  his own specific file_operations in specific ways. See https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/vfs.html?highlight=file_operations#struct-file-operations or like https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ chapter 3 . TTY has default file operations https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L3521 used prominently in PTY https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/pty.c#L927 .

I see n_tty_read is referenced in tty_ldisc_ops n_tty_ops at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/n_tty.c#L2515 . The kernel documentation mentions a line discipline ldisc. The default line discipline N_TTY seems to be assigned in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/tty_ldisc.c#L795 when allocating tty struct at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L3121 . Also, chapter 18 in LDD3 is about TTY devices, might be interesting read for you.

This answer (which only considers VMIN and VTIME) is incomplete because the question is vague. The attributes VMIN and VTIME are only used when both (1) non-canonical mode is specified and (2) the serial terminal was opened in blocking mode (i.e. O_NONBLOCK is not specified). There are other modes in which the serial terminal can be nonblocking for reading.
