Why is it that when this ttyUSB is addressed via C, sometimes something is written to stdout and sometimes not?
Hi I have the following code written in c for a ttyUSB device. Some parts of the code are from another source:
// C library headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Linux headers
#include <fcntl.h> // Contains file controls like O_RDWR
#include <errno.h> // Error integer and strerror() function
#include <termios.h> // Contains POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <unistd.h> // write(), read(), close()
// Custom headers
//// klammern
////#include "some_functions.h"

////int write_log(char*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <at-command>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
  }
  int serial_port = open("/dev/ttyUSB4", O_RDWR);
  // Check for errors
  if (serial_port < 0) {
      printf("Error %i from open: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      exit(1);
  }
  struct termios tty;

  // Read in existing settings, and handle any error
  if(tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  }

  tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Clear parity bit, disabling parity (most common)
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // Clear stop field, only one stop bit used in communication (most common)
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; // Clear all bits that set the data size
  tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 bits per byte (most common)
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable RTS/CTS hardware flow control (most common)
  tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Turn on READ & ignore ctrl lines (CLOCAL = 1)

  tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; // Disable echo
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; // Disable erasure
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; // Disable new-line echo
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG; // Disable interpretation of INTR, QUIT and SUSP
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Turn off s/w flow ctrl
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL); // Disable any special handling of received bytes

  tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST; // Prevent special interpretation of output bytes (e.g. newline chars)
  tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; // Prevent conversion of newline to carriage return/line feed
  // tty.c_oflag &= ~OXTABS; // Prevent conversion of tabs to spaces (NOT PRESENT ON LINUX)
  // tty.c_oflag &= ~ONOEOT; // Prevent removal of C-d chars (0x004) in output (NOT PRESENT ON LINUX)

  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 50;    // Wait for up to 1s (10 deciseconds), returning as soon as any data is received.; 5 sek ^= 50
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

  // Set in/out baud rate to be 9600
  cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);

  // Save tty settings, also checking for error
  if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
      printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
  }

  // Write to serial port
  //unsigned char msg[] = { 'a', 't', '+', 'c', 'g', 'p', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'r', '=', '1', '\r' };
  unsigned int argv1_len = strlen(argv[1]);
  char msg[argv1_len+2]; // unsigned char
  strcpy(msg, argv[1]); 
  ////write_log(msg);
  strcat(msg, "\r");
  
  write(serial_port, msg, sizeof(msg));
  
  // Allocate memory for read buffer, set size according to your needs
  char read_buf [256];

  // Normally you wouldn't do this memset() call, but since we will just receive
  // ASCII data for this example, we'll set everything to 0 so we can
  // call printf() easily.
  memset(&read_buf, '\0', sizeof(read_buf));

  // Read bytes. The behaviour of read() (e.g. does it block?,
  // how long does it block for?) depends on the configuration
  // settings above, specifically VMIN and VTIME
  int num_bytes = read(serial_port, &read_buf, sizeof(read_buf));

  // n is the number of bytes read. n may be 0 if no bytes were received, and can also be -1 to signal an error.
  if (num_bytes < 0) {
      printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));
      close(serial_port);
      return 1;
  }else if (num_bytes == 0) {
      printf("0");
      close(serial_port);
      return 1;
  }

  // Here we assume we received ASCII data, but you might be sending raw bytes (in that case, don't try and
  // print it to the screen like this!)
  //printf("Read %i bytes. Received message: %s", num_bytes, read_buf);
  printf("%s", read_buf);
  fflush(stdout); 
 
  ////removeLeadingNewlines(read_buf);
  
  ////write_log(read_buf);

  close(serial_port);
  return 0; // success
}

And this is my Makefile, it builds with no errors or warnings:
WARNFLAGS = -W -Wall -Werror
OPTFLAGS = -O3
DEBUGFLAGS = -ggdb3 -DDEBUG
CFLAGS += $(WARNFLAGS)
binaries = at_commander

ifdef DEBUG
  CFLAGS += $(DEBUGFLAGS)
else
  CFLAGS += $(OPTFLAGS)
endif

all: $(binaries)

at_commander: some_functions.c

clean:
    $(RM) *~ $(binaries) *.o

The question is why what is now being output to the console irregularly:
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at

OK
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at

OK
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at

OK
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart# ./at_commander at

OK
root@OpenMPTCProuter:~/autostart#

First I thought it has something to do with flushing, but maybe it has something to do with wrong timing in my code.
Thank you in advance!

Probably not related to your problem, but are you sure that you want to write the terminating \0 byte to the ttyUSB? write(serial_port, msg, sizeof(msg)); If not, you should use strlen instead of sizeof.

If you assume some flushing issue, then you should add \n at the end of your format strings. But the streams should be flushed when the program exits.

Maybe your read_buff is all zeros.

For debugging you should print the return value of read in any case. And maybe the content of read_buf  as hex values. Maybe you get some nonprintable response.

You should subtract 1 from the size of read_buf when calling read() to allow room for the null terminator.

@Gerhardh They have fflush(stdout); right after printf().

My guess is that for some reason the device isn't responding within 1 second sometimes.

@Barmar only after one of the prints.

Try to open() with O_NOCTTY.

If you suspect a timing issue, did you try to wait a bit? Or just try to read multiple times?

@Gerhardh It's the only one that prints the response from the device. The rest are all error messages. But as you say, everything should be flushed when the program exits, so this is redundant.

Thank you for all the responses, unfortunately I can only test and try your suggestions at work next week

If num_bytes is 256 printf(printf("%s", read_buf); will read past the end of read_buf looking for the null terminator. You could limit it using printf("%.*s", num_bytes, read_buf);.


Why is it that when this ttyUSB is addressed via C, ...

"A ttyUSB device" is not an end-point device (such as a flash drive), but rather a communications interface. Presumably you have something connected to this "ttyUSB device" using a cable, and your intent is to communicate with that connected device. However you completely neglect to mention anything about any other device.

... sometimes something is written to stdout and sometimes not?

Your use of the noun "something" is ambiguous and completely disregards the fact that this involves (a) a command message is transmitted by your program, (b) that message has to be received and processed by a remote unit, (c) a response message has to be transmitted by that remote unit, and (d) that response message has to be received/read by your program.
In other words that "something" is a response from a remote unit/device, and the failure (of your program) to "sometimes not" indicates that all of the required steps with that remote unit/device in that sequence were not successful .
There are only a few clues in your post to identify the connected device that your program is trying to communicate with. One is a commented-out initialization. There are references to "at-command". So apparently the connected device is a modem that uses the AT (aka Hayes) command set.

Your program as posted has a variety of minor issues, most of which have been mentioned in comments. IMO the salient bug in your program is expecting to receive the entire response when using a noncanonical read() with a timeout.
Your program configures the serial terminal to noncanonical mode using the assignment
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;

The two termios attributes that control when and what a read() will return are assigned the following (note the discrepancy between the actual value and the comment):
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 50;    // Wait for up to 1s (10 deciseconds), returning as soon as any data is received.; 5 sek ^= 50
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

Per the termios man page, you have setup a read with timeout:

   MIN == 0, TIME > 0 (read with timeout)
         TIME specifies the limit for a timer in tenths of a second.  The timer is started when read(2) is called.  read(2) returns  either  when  at
         least  one byte of data is available, or when the timer expires.  If the timer expires without any input becoming available, read(2) returns
         0.  If data is already available at the time of the call to read(2), the call behaves as though the data was received immediately after  the
         call.


The salient point is that the timeout will occur only when no data is available. This configuration does not mean that read() will wait for the VTIME duration, and then return with all available data. Rather, as soon as at least one byte is available, the read() could return (with just that single byte).
Your program's results indicates that the full response from the modem is the string \r\nOK\r\n. That is six character consisting of CR, LF,'O', 'K',  CR, and LF. This is indicated on the "good" output of a blank line after the command, the OK text, and your shell prompt showing up on a new line. Omit any of the mentioned control characters, and you would then see a different "good" output.
When your program "sometimes not" display a response, the
read() probably returned with only the first character of the six-byte response. When your program prints that first character of the response, you do not notice it because (1) it's a control character (i.e. carriage return) rather than a printable character, and (2) the cursor is already at the first column, so another CR does nothing.
To verify this hypothesis, revise the print statement to be more informative and distinctive (as @Gerhardh suggested in his comment).
-   printf("%s", read_buf);
+   printf("received %d: \'%s\'\n", num_bytes, read_buf);



To read the entire response try
  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 2;    // rtn after 0.2 sec of idle after first char
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 80;


I reinserted the expanded print statement and was able to confirm the above hypothesis. I then added your suggested changes so it works now, thank you very much! Next time I will give a little more context, as I had already tested the behavior several times with the excluded print statement and picocom

You're welcome, you posted an interesting problem that I couldn't solve by just review. After running your code with a modem, I ended up with a better understanding of the VMIN=0 and VTIME>0 mode, and had to revise/improve an old answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996171/linux-blocking-vs-non-blocking-serial-read/26006680#26006680

What do you mean with The question is why what is now being output to the console irregularly?
A modem sends an OK answer preceded and followed by CR LF characters (a pair of characters) so what you receive in the buffer is \r\nOK\r\n, which prints as you show, leavind a blank line before the ok.  This is after you have detected that you read something, use the following statement to convert your data buffer into a printable buffer.
But you have assumed (erroneously) that the buffer you have read is printable with printf(), using a %s format specifier.  That is wrong, you can print only null delimited strings, and the read() system call will not put the nul character for you.
You have an easy solution for that:

specify one value less (to allow space to later put a nul character yourself, after the data) when calling read (use sizeof buffer - 1, instead of sizeof buffer)
put a nul char in the position of the last character read (read_buff[num_bytes] = 0;).

You will print a blank line, followed by OK and a second new line, making your output as you see it.
What is wrong with what you observe? That's the effect of printing a new line, OK and a new newline.  And that is what you get.
BTW there's no flushing when you deal with read() or write().  Only when you use printf() you are subject to flushing. But on a terminal, printf flushes all output as soon as it sees a \n character in the parameter list, so it should not be an issue.

Apparently you didn't see the memset() before the read(), which zeroes-out the receiving buffer and automatically provides a null terminator as long as the read-count is less than the full request. The "fix" you advocate would only make a difference in that one case (which is not happening yet). @Barmar 's first comment above mentions a simpler remedy to handle that case..

I didn't see it, but if that is the case, then there's still a U.B. in the code, because the read specifies the full buffer size to fill data in.  This can result in a ful read leaving no space unfilled with nulls, making the buffer not null ended, and not printf()able.

It is better to specify a one less buffer size when reading and then, after checking for errors (in which the index could be negative) just put a single null character at index num_bytes, which can only be 0..sizeof data_buffer - 2 (total sizeof data_buffer - 1 bytes)  so you will have to put only one null at the proper place.

He is always reading a small amount of bytes, because the modem response is short.  But in case he gets a full buffer, the later printf() will print a lot of garbage and possibly crash.  Anyway, filling the buffer with sizeof buffer bytes to avoid putting a single null character is in my humble opinion a waste of cpu time.

I fully agree that the code change you propose is preferred (and it's how I always code it). But this will not change in any way the results the OP sees. What you propose is not the solution to the root problem of the OP's program.

@sawdust, I started my answer asking what should be the correct answer, because a modem precedes and postpones a pair of CR LF characters to each answer, and this is what makes the answer to appear as such.  The observed answer should be the correct one, and this is why I ask what should be the correct (non irregular) answer.  He ends each printed sentence with a '\n' char, and the "\r\nOK\r\n" answer of the modem makes the blank line between the messages.  What is wrong there?
