How to fix mangled output from Arduino Serial?
I have written a code using the termios library to read serial data from an Arduino Mega. It is my first time using this library so I am still trying to learn how it and just serial communication in general works.
The end goal of my code is to send a JSON-eqsue packet containing various sets of information. However, as of right now, I am just starting with a sample example message. Everything seems fine, but instead of getting an output that simply says:
Example Text.
Example Text.
Example Text.

I instead get this:
Et.Example Text.Example Text.
Example Text.xt.Example Text.

Mind you, this is received every second even though it's only supposed to send the text once every second. I think it's an issue with the buffer, but, again, I am confused on how the serial communication protocol works in depth.
Below is the computer and Arduino code, respectively. (And sorry if the code is a bit over the place; this is just for practice and prototyping.)
// serial.cpp

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int serial_port;
char machine_data[1024];
int max_fd;

int serial_setup(char conn[]) {

    serial_port = open(conn, O_RDWR); // or "/dev/ttyS0" for a physical serial port

    // Boilerplate code for the default serial settings
    if (serial_port == -1) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening serial port." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Serial port is open." << std::endl;

    struct termios tty;
    memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

    if (tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error getting serial port attributes." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cfsetospeed(&tty, B38400); // Set baud rate
    cfsetispeed(&tty, B38400);

    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Disable parity
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // One stop bit
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 data bits

    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable hardware flow control
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Enable receiver, ignore modem control lines

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Disable software flow control

    tty.c_lflag = 0; // No canonical mode

    tty.c_oflag = 0; // No output processing

    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // Read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5; // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error setting serial port attributes." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Finished the setup for the serial port." << std::endl;


    return 0;

}

std::string read_serial() {

    std::string return_string;
    // This section is for the setup for the select function.
    fd_set rfds;
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(serial_port, &rfds);
    max_fd = serial_port + 1;
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

    int ready = select(max_fd, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
    if (ready > 0) {
        std::cout << "Data available." << std::endl;    
        int num_data = read(serial_port, machine_data, sizeof(machine_data));
        return_string = machine_data;
        std::cout << "Completed a read function." << std::endl;
    }

    else { 
        std::cout << "Did not complete." << std::endl;

    }

    return return_string;

}

int main() {
    char serial_port[] = "/dev/ttyACM0";

    int status = serial_setup(serial_port);

    while (true) {
        std::string text = read_serial(); 

        std::cout << text << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;

}

// exp_serial.ino

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.write("Example Text.");
    delay(1000);
}

EDIT 1: So, after suggestions from luantkow, I got a different output, but instead of it being mangled, it was just cut up:
e Text.
Exam
ple Text.

I decided to use additional print functions to print how manhy bytes were actually read and to dump the contents of machine_data each time. Here is a sample of the output:
Serial port is open.
Finished the setup for the serial port.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 5
---> Examp
Dumping machine_data array.
Examp
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 8
---> le Text.
Dumping machine_data array.
le Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 13
---> Example Text.
Dumping machine_data array.
Example Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 10
---> Example Te
Dumping machine_data array.
Example Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 3
---> xt.
Dumping machine_data array.
xt.mple Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 4
---> Exam
Dumping machine_data array.
Example Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 9
---> ple Text.
Dumping machine_data array.
ple Text.ext.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 13
---> Example Text.
Dumping machine_data array.
Example Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 8
---> Example 
Dumping machine_data array.
Example Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 5
---> Text.
Dumping machine_data array.
Text.le Text.
Data available.
Completed a read function.
Number of bytes availaible: 3
---> Exa
Dumping machine_data array.
Exat.le Text.

So, it seems that the reading from the serial port itself and the overwriting of the array each time seems to be an issue. Again, just more debugging info.

You are ignoring the result of read, when you simply assign char array to string, the string will look for first 0 byte to decide how long the value is. Change: return_string = machine_data; to return_string.assign(machine_data,  num_data);. You are also missing the error handling, also you use select without making the descriptor non blocking add O_NONBLOCK to O_RDWR

I realized that you configure read behavior with VMIN and VTIME, ignore my the suggestion about O_NONBLOCK.

Got it. Output is looking better, but now it just cuts the "Example Text." in pieces. So one output would be "Example Te" and then the next immediate output is "xt."
On another note, how did you learn how this stuff works? I realize this is closer to the hardware in terms of coding, so I am curious how to learn these things for myself.

It looks like multipel threads are attempting to write at once. You need to lock that down. The simplest method is via a mutex.

"Below is the computer and Arduino code," - Then you have stated your problem poorly. You have not described at all what executes this "code using the termios library". Have you verified the Arduino actually outputs that data that you expect? You claim there should be lines of text, but your Arduino code does not seem to output any control characters! Perhaps you need to use a PC with a terminal emulation program to view that output? Also your termios code needs improvement; see Setting Terminal Modes Properly

"EDIT 1: ... output ... was just cut up" - Because you have configured termios to read "with a timeout". That does not mean that read() will fetch as much data as possible in the VTIME interval. See my answer to another problem involving a similar read "with a timeout": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78953617/why-is-it-that-when-this-ttyusb-is-addressed-via-c-sometimes-something-is-writt .  Put simply, termios is not configured to read a complete message or "line", so reading a fragment is expected.

As mentioned in the comment, read when successful returns number of bytes that was actually read and can be used. In your code, you call
char machine_data[1024];
[...]
std::string return_string
[...]
return_string = machine_data;

Which effectively calls assignment operator on your string, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D:

Replaces the contents with those of null-terminated character string pointed to by s as if by assign(s, Traits::length(s)).

So std::string checks the machine_data content looking for first byte that is set to 0. As machine_data is a global variable, you may assume that it was pre-initialized with zeroes. Your result will have have a "tail" made of read results that managed to read slightly more data. To fix that, use string's assign method that gets pointer to first character and number of characters you want to use:
return_string.assign(machine_data, read_result);

As you already noticed, this won't be enough to get data line-by-line. You need to prepare your code for possibility that:

only part of line will be read and another attempt is required to read whole line

more than one line will be read at once
  #include <fcntl.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <termios.h>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <cstring>
  #include <algorithm>

  int serial_setup(char conn[]) {
      int serial_port = open(conn, O_RDONLY);

      // Boilerplate code for the default serial settings
      if (serial_port == -1) {
          std::cerr << "Error opening serial port: %s" << strerror(errno) <<  std::endl;
          return serial_port;
      }

      std::clog << "Serial port is open." << std::endl;

      struct termios tty;
      memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));

      if (tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
          close(serial_port);
          std::cerr << "Error getting serial port attributes: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
          return -1;
      }

      cfsetospeed(&tty, B38400); // Set baud rate
      cfsetispeed(&tty, B38400);

      tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Disable parity
      tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // One stop bit
      tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
      tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 data bits

      tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable hardware flow control
      tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Enable receiver, ignore modem control lines

      tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Disable software flow control

      tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; // No canonical mode

      tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0; // Read doesn't block
      tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5; // 0.5 seconds read timeout

      if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
          close(serial_port);
          std::cerr << "Error setting serial port attributes: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
          return -1;
      }

      std::clog << "Finished the setup for the serial port." << std::endl;

      return serial_port;
  }

  std::string read_line_serial(int serial_descriptor, char* buffer, size_t buffer_size, char** data_end)
  {
      char* data_start = buffer;
      do
      {
          char* end_of_line = std::find(data_start, *data_end, '\n');

          if(end_of_line != *data_end) // The new line character was found
          {
              std::string result(data_start, end_of_line);
              end_of_line++; // We don't need the '\n', lets jump over it
              size_t data_left = *data_end - end_of_line;
              memmove(buffer, end_of_line, data_left * sizeof(char));
              *data_end = buffer + data_left;
              return result;
          }

          fd_set rfds;
          FD_ZERO(&rfds);
          FD_SET(serial_descriptor, &rfds);

          int max_fd = serial_descriptor + 1;
          struct timeval timeout;
          timeout.tv_sec = 5;
          timeout.tv_usec = 10000;

          int ready = select(max_fd, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
          if(ready == 0)
          {
              return std::string();
          }
          size_t already_in_buffer = *data_end - buffer;
          if(already_in_buffer == buffer_size)
          {
              std::cerr << "Buffer overflow, dropping line" << std::endl;
              already_in_buffer = 0;
              *data_end = buffer;
          }
          int num_data = read(serial_descriptor, *data_end, buffer_size - already_in_buffer);
          if(num_data == -1)
          {
              std::cerr << "Read failed with: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
              return std::string();
          }
          data_start = *data_end;
          *data_end += num_data;
      }
      while(true);
  }

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {

      if(argc < 2)
      {
          std::cerr << "Provide path to serial port" << std::endl;
          return 1;
      }

      int serial_handle = serial_setup(argv[1]);

      if(serial_handle == -1)
      {
          return 1;
      }

      constexpr size_t buffer_size = 1024;
      char buffer[buffer_size];
      char* data_position = buffer;

      while (true) {
          std::string text = read_line_serial(serial_handle, buffer, buffer_size, &data_position);

          std::cout << text << std::endl;
      }

      close(serial_handle);

      return 0;
  }



You may simplify your code, by using canonical mode (which you explicitly disables in serial_setup: See https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr:

In canonical mode:

Input is made available line by line. An input line is available when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at the start of line). Except in the case of EOF, the line delimiter is included in the buffer returned by read(2).
Line editing is enabled (ERASE, KILL; and if the IEXTEN flag is set: WERASE, REPRINT, LNEXT). A read(2) returns at most one line of input; if the read(2) requested fewer bytes than are available in the current line of input, then only as many bytes as requested are read, and the remaining characters will be available for a future read(2).
In noncanonical mode input is available immediately (without the user having to type a line-delimiter character), no input processing is performed, and line editing is disabled. The settings of MIN (c_cc[VMIN]) and TIME (c_cc[VTIME]) determine the circumstances in which a read(2) completes;


Canonical mode seems to do exactly what you need:
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <termios.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstring>
    
    int serial_setup(char conn[]) {
    
        int serial_port = open(conn, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
    
        // Boilerplate code for the default serial settings
        if (serial_port == -1) {
            std::cerr << "Error opening serial port: %s" << strerror(errno) <<  std::endl;
            return serial_port;
        }
    
        std::clog << "Serial port is open." << std::endl;
    
        struct termios tty;
        memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
    
        if (tcgetattr(serial_port, &tty) != 0) {
            close(serial_port);
            std::cerr << "Error getting serial port attributes: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    
        cfsetospeed(&tty, B38400); // Set baud rate
        cfsetispeed(&tty, B38400);
    
        tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // Disable parity
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // One stop bit
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        tty.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 data bits
    
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; // Disable hardware flow control
        tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; // Enable receiver, ignore modem control lines
    
        tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // Disable software flow control
    
        tty.c_lflag |= ICANON; // Canonical mode
            
        if (tcsetattr(serial_port, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
            close(serial_port);
            std::cerr << "Error setting serial port attributes: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    
        std::clog << "Finished the setup for the serial port." << std::endl;
    
        return serial_port;
    }
    
    std::string read_line_serial(int serial_descriptor)
    {
        constexpr size_t buffer_size = 4096;
        char buffer[buffer_size];
    
        fd_set rfds;
    
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);
        FD_SET(serial_descriptor, &rfds);
    
        int max_fd = serial_descriptor + 1;
    
        struct timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 5;
        timeout.tv_usec = 10000;
    
        int ready = select(max_fd, &rfds, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
    
        if(ready == 0)
        {
            return std::string();
        }
    
        int num_data = read(serial_descriptor, buffer, buffer_size);
    
        if(num_data == -1)
        {
            std::cerr << "Read failed with: " << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return std::string();
        }
    
        return std::string(buffer, num_data);
    }
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
        if(argc < 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Provide path to serial port" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    
        int serial_handle = serial_setup(argv[1]);
    
        if(serial_handle == -1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    
        while (true) {
            std::string text = read_line_serial(serial_handle);
    
            std::cout << text;
            // We don't use std::endl because text will contain '\n'
            // but endl also flushes the stream:
            std::cout.flush();
        }
    
        close(serial_handle);
    
        return 0;
    }
    


Downvote for an answer that does not adhere to Setting Terminal Modes Properly.

Thank you for providing the link, I've amended the example code to set only ICANON value in c_lflag and not touch c_oflag at all as example only receives value.

Okay, but your canonical example has an incomplete initialization, which can lead to erratic, unreliable program behavior. Specifically, the line termination definitions are left to chance. Moreover, you (and the OP) seem to assume that the Arduino is sending lines of text. I see no evidence of that. The #1 problem the OP continues to have IMO is ensuring that strings are null-terminated in the buffer (which is mistakenly seen as "overwriting of the array").
